# More object oriented sql in python

Tags: python, sql, object-oriented-database

I am thinking about bringing sql code into python objects and using more of its special methods that the data model provides. Here are my thoughts. What is your opinion? How would you do it?

Lets define some tables

```
table users
    id: int
    username: string
    group_id: int

table groups
    id: int
    name: string

table values:
    id: int
    value_type_id: int
    value: string
    user_id: int

table value_types:
    id: int
    name: int
```

and lets say we have appropriate classes in python named User, Group, Value, ValueType.

To get all values by a specific user, I would write:

```
values = Value.db
values.user.id == request["user_id"]
```

or if there is no foreign key specified

```
values.user_id == request["user_id"]
```

to get the values out of database, I would just iterate like everyone else does:

```
for value in values:
-> select * from values where user_id = ?
```

if I don't want all the columns, I would specify the columns before iteration maybe like this:

```
for value in values >> (values.value_type_id):
-> select value_type_id from values where user_id = ?"
```

But maybe the formation above is overkill and too complicated. Maybe I should use something more simpler like:

```
for value in values.fields(values.value_type_id):
-> select value_type_id from values where user_id = ?"
```

if we would like to get ValueType objects as well with all the values returned, I would do something like this:

```
values_types = Values.db
for (value_type, value) in (value_types + values):
-> select * from value_types join values ...
```

to add joins, that have no foreign key, I would need to specify the join conditions separately, like this

```
 groups = Group.db
 values.user.group_id == groups.id
 for (value, group) in (values + groups):
 -> select users.*,groups.* from values join users join groups
```

The comparison part is easy. We can easily emulate <, <=, >, >=, ==, in. All those comparison functions will alter the db manager sql conditions.

For grouping I am thinking about using division like this. What would you use?

```
for value in values.fields(values.value_type_id) / values.value_type_id:
-> select value_type_id from values groupd by value_type_id
```

For left joins, I would use +=.

```
for (value, group) in (values += groups):
 -> select users.*,groups.* from values join users left join groups
```

What I am thinking right now, is how to implement ordering, having and distinct. No idea yet. Maybe you can help?

Well, these were my initial raw thoughts. Your thoughts are welcome. How would you do it? What would you do differently?

Comment: Take a look at SQLAlchemy if you want to bridge relational data and objects. Don't reinvent this (considerably complex) wheel.

Comment: Also take a look at Django's ORM capabilities. Those can quite easily be used outside Django and provide a very pythonic database interface.

Comment: There is a fundamental problem that I would mention here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch

Comment: SQLAlchemy is good but is it readable? I haven't used it but I will take a look.

Django is not pythonic at all if things go complex. In fact, I tried to create a ManyToMany relationship without a middle table and found myself stuck where half of the code was pythonic but the other half was string processing.

Thanx for the wiki link. Going through it now.

Comment: Check out Peewee. Very similar to django's. https://github.com/coleifer/peewee